# appendFile is replacing the content

Tags: html, node.js, append

I just started with node.js, and I came across appendFile which it appends the content to the end of the file, but when I execute it my code id replacing the content altogether with the data.

here is the code.

```
var http = require('http');
    var file = require('fs');
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      var fd = file.open('default.html','w',function(err){
        if(err)throw err;
    });
    file.appendFile('default.html',"<p>Hi,this to inform you that i really don't care</p>",function(err){});
      return res.end();
    }).listen(8080);
```

the defalult file is

```
 <!doctype>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>File</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        Hi, EveryOne
    </h1>
</html>
```

the output I get is

```
<p>Hi,this to inform you that i really don't care</p>
```

can anyone please tell me why this is happening or what i'am doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have opened the file in 'w' i.e. write mode and then doing the operation on it. You really do not need to open the file before appending to it.

```
var fd = file.open('default.html','w',function(err){
        if(err)throw err;
    });
```

I do not see, you doing anything useful with it, so this code is not needed. If you do need it then open the file in 'append' mode by replacing `'w'` with `'a'` and remember to close the file too.

However, as I said you can simply append using the method rather then opening the file.